# Try&catch clause in snowflake scripting

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wonder if is there equivalent of try catch blocks from javascript in pure sql in Snowflake.
I want to have a procedure which will check all views and does something with them, but some of the views are invalid and these I want to skip.
The javascript version looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure test_views_js()
returns varchar
language javascript
as 

$$
var sql = "select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views where table_schema='TEST'";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement ({sqlText:sql});
var result_set = stmt.execute();
var cnt = 0;
while (result_set.next()){
try{
    var sql_text = "select count(*) from "+result_set.getColumnValue(1);
    var stmt2 =  snowflake.createStatement ({sqlText:sql_text});
    var r = stmt2.execute();
    r.next();
    cnt+=r.getColumnValue(1);
}catch (err){
continue
}

}
return cnt;
$$
```

Can I achieve the same result with sql?

UPDATE

I am getting syntax error when I try to put exception in the loop. When it's in different place syntax is valid, but 'break is outside of loop' . Maybe there is some obvious typo that i cannot see?

```
create or replace procedure test_views() 
returns integer not null 
language sql 
as 
declare 
sel varchar; 
row_cnt integer default 0; 
res resultset default 
    (select table_name 
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views 
     where table_schema='TEST') ; 
c1 cursor for res; 

begin 
    for row_variable in c1 do 
        row_cnt:= (select count(*) from view_test); 
        exception when statement_error then continue; 
    end for; 
    return row_cnt; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use exception inside loop. Instead of:

```
for row_variable in c1 do 
        row_cnt:= (select count(*) from view_test); 
        exception when statement_error then continue; 
end for;
```

All the code should be wrapped with its own `BEGIN EXCEPTION END` block.

```
create or replace procedure test_views() 
returns integer not null 
language sql 
as
declare 
sel varchar; 
row_cnt integer default 0; 
res resultset default 
    (select table_name 
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views 
     where table_schema='TEST') ; 
c1 cursor for res; 

begin 
    for row_variable in c1 do 
        begin
            row_cnt:= (select count(*) from view_test); 
        exception when other then continue; 
        end;
    end for; 
    return row_cnt; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there RAISE/EXCEPTION constructs documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions.html

Comment: But I don't want to raise exception. I want to continue on error. I couldn't find my way around that.

Comment: Did you read the section on handling exceptions: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions.html#handling-an-exception ?
Just catch the exception and use a CONTINUE statement

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I tried at first place. But I am getting syntax error when I try to put exception in the loop. When it's in different place syntax is valid, but 'break is outside of loop' . Maybe there is some obvious typo that i cannot see?

Comment: create or replace procedure test_views()
    returns integer not null
    language sql
    as 
    declare
        sel varchar;
        row_cnt integer default 0;
        res resultset default (select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views where table_schema='TEST') ;
        c1 cursor for res;
    begin
    for row_variable in c1 do
        row_cnt:= (select count(*) from view_test);
        exception
          when statement_error then
          continue;
    end for;
    return row_cnt;
    end;